# Mi splash screen se inicia despues de la splash screen por defecto

Tags: android, android-studio, jetpack-compose

Estoy empezando un nuevo proyecto en Android Studio y Jetpack Compose. Estoy intentando hacer una Splash Screen, y solo tengo dos Screen, la Splash y un main (sin contenido ninguno). También tengo un navController y poco más.

Esta es mi Splash Screen y por mucho que tenga un `LaunchedEffect()`, a la hora de iniciar la app aparece el Splash Screen del tema por defecto de Android Studio.

```
@Composable
fun SplashScreen(navController:NavHostController) {
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true){
        delay(3000)
        navController.popBackStack()
        navController.navigate(AppScreen.MainScreen.rutaPantalla)
    }


    Splash()
}

@Composable
fun Splash(){
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Gray),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ){
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.logo_test),
            contentDescription = "Logo de la empresa",
            Modifier.size(313.dp,123.dp)
        )
        Text("que es esto?",
        fontSize = 45.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Black
        )

    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ShowSplashScreenPreview(){
    Splash()
}
```

La verdad es que no se si esta es la forma correcta de realizar una splash Screen.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de la etiqueta `<style>` en el archivo themes.xml pega lo siguiente

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Te dejo mi código de ejemplo:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.CelFinder" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
       
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Un cordial saludo compañeros,

Logre encontrar la solución al tema del Splash Screen automatico, en el manifiesto de la app se puede borrar del manifiesto o cambiar la imagen en la linea de     android icon , hay que probar la posibilidad de editarlo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    **android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"-> ( Delete or Change)
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AsistentePersonalDelMercaderista"
    tools:targetApi="31">
```